# What is the difference between CreateWhitespace and CreateSignificantWhitespace in XmlDocument

Tags: c#, .net, xml, vb.net, xmldocument

When using `XmlDocument` found in `System.Xml`, you gain access to `CreateWhitespace` and `CreateSignificantWhitespace`. I can't find any information on when you should use one over the other.

What is the difference between them and how should I use them?

Link to: [CreateWhitespace on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.createwhitespace?view=netframework-4.8)

Link to: [CreateSignificantWhitespace on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.createsignificantwhitespace?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: It's defined in the [XML Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#sec-white-space)

Comment: Thank you @Damien_The_Unbeliever! This explained the intent and purpose, but does that mean that `CreateWhitespace` and `CreateSignificantWhitespace` work differently in code? As far as I noticed, they both do the same thing and is both included in the final output of the created XML file.

Comment: The first creates an `XmlWhitespace`: *Represents white space in element content*. The other an `XmlSignificantWhitespace`: *Represents white space between markup in a mixed content node or white space within an xml:space= 'preserve' scope. This is also referred to as significant white space*. The `'preserve' scope` meaning is explained in the linked documentation.